# Unable to Git clone with a second personal github account

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-clone

I have added a second github account on my laptop in addition to the first one. The document https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-use-multiple-github-accounts-with-one-computer-c9ba3f851b75 did help a lot but I am facing issues while cloning a repo which is accessible from the second github account.

I generated the keys `id_rsa_unaccount` and `id_rsa_unaccount.pub` and added the content of `id_rsa_unaccount.pub` to my ssh field in the second github account.

```
>ls ~/.ssh  
config          id_rsa          id_rsa.pub      id_rsa_unaccount    id_rsa_unaccount.pub
```

Updated the `~/.ssh/config`

```
# Account 1 (work or personal) - the default config
Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# Account 2 (personal) - the config we are adding
Host github-unaccount
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_unaccount
```

Also setup

```
git config user.name "Gupastha" 
git config user.email "asthagupta92+8@gmail.com"
```

However when I tried to git clone the repo, I see

```
git clone git@github-unaccount:Noble-Missions/itakeactions.git 
Cloning into 'itakeactions'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I also went through multiple stack overflow links for the same but I couldnt find a solution to the cloning yet. Can anyone please nudge me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if your second key is recognized:

```
ssh -Tv github-unaccount
```

No need for `git@` since it is included in your `~/.ssh/config`

Then use, assuming Linux-like environment:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'
git clone github-unaccount:Noble-Missions/itakeactions.git
```

You will see what keys are considered during the clone operation.

The [OP Astha Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2899485/astha-gupta) confirms the wrong key is used because, from [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70898935/unable-to-git-clone-with-a-second-personal-github-account/70899211#comment125339283_70899211):

> I had an additional entry in the ssh `config`: `Host *`, which was pointing to `id_rsa`.

Comment: Oh executing `ssh -Tv github-unaccount` is pointing to first account.
```
Offering public key: /Users/astha.gupta/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:blah explicit agent
Server accepts key: /Users/astha.gupta/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:blah explicit agent
Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com
Hi astha-first-account! You've successfully authenticated
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3068, received 3256 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 18356.3, received 19481.1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: @AsthaGupta Double-check the content of  `/Users/astha.gupta/.ssh/config`: the Host entry named `github-unaccount` should refer to `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_unaccount`, the second key.

Comment: yeah its 100% that. I wonder if there a way to load this info into the terminal
# Account 2 (personal) - the config we are adding
Host github-unaccount
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_unaccount

Comment: Also i compared the content of ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_rsa_unaccount and they are different

Comment: Also there is a `debug1: Exit status 1` in the end of `ssh -Tv github-unaccount`. Is that smth sinister?

Comment: Oh I found out, I had an additional entry in the ssh config `Host *` which was pointing to id_rsa. My bad.

Comment: @AsthaGupta Good catch, well done. I have edited the answer to reflect your finding.